# How to define path 

Tags: php, zend-framework, path

I know it may be simple question to all experienced developer..
 I have trapped with the problem that how to set the path in bootstrap file

like ......

when i work on local ... i use this path

```
 $filenam = "C:/xampp/htdocs/application/public/pdf_profile/$pdfname.html";
```

when i upload this particular file... i need to make change  ..in this path ..like this

```
$filenam = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/public/pdf_profile/$pdfname.html";
```

i want to know is there any solution to prevent change again n again .. like  any change in bootstrap file .. how to define path in this way that i have no need to worry about path.. at time of local or live
Basically am working with zend

thanks in advance !

Comment: What is $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] on your local machine?

Comment: If you store upload information in the database, don't store the full path: store only the part you need to know. (In this case, probably $pdfname)

Comment: @george $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ..is basically path of live folder

Comment: AlReece45 ..nah .dun go with uploading.. its about how should i define identical path .. by which at tym of local and uploding file .. i have no need to change it again n again

Comment: That's not the question I asked: What is $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] **on your local machine**? Emphasis added to point out the purpose of the question.  I know what that server variable means.  The ultimate point, you should try to use the same directory structure below the document root, so that it's easy to transfer between local and production.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define a constant in your index.php

```
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

You can use this constant like so everywhere in your application

```
$filename = BASE_PATH . '/pdf_profile/' . $pdfname . '.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

another simple way, set an constant in your initialize.php

```
// Assign file paths to PHP constants
// __FILE__ returns the current path to this file
// dirname() returns the path to the parent directory
define("PRIVATE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
define("PROJECT_PATH", dirname(PRIVATE_PATH));
define("PUBLIC_PATH", PROJECT_PATH . '/public');
```

Comment: but how shoul i use this .. in the file ?
i meant plz elaborate it

Answer (score 0):

I think ,in case of XAMPP (working locally) the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] should return you "C:/xampp/htdocs/application/"

Comment: nah ..its not returning .. local path ..thats the main problem :(

Answer (score 0):

If you use Zend_Tool to generate your project, it should automatically add code in your index.php that defines a constant called APPLICATION_PATH which is an absolute path to your application folder in a ZF project.

All files related to a project should stay under the same tree, you should put all your projects into subfolders of your document root and create virtual hosts.

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/
    myapp/
        application/
        data/
        library/
        public/
        tests/
    anotherapp/
        application/
        data/
        library/
        public/
        tests/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, u need to define a constant. And its very straight forward. Here you go -

```
define('UPLOADPATH','/work/images/');
```

where,
UPLOADPATH is the name of a constant. (you can give a name of your choice)
and,
following that, is the path.

In my case it was in C drive under wamp, www folder. Hence i have only provided path inside www